# How to place small rectangles on a path geometry in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have great need to place small rectangles on an ellipse circumference or Path Geometry. the y value is not known until runtime. the x value is what i need to solve based on any given (y)

Thanks in advance

Mark

More info as requested:
I have a straight Vertical column that has depth markers at various heights (y) values. I am required to create an ellipse callout to the left of the vertical column for each vertical depth marker inside the Vertical column. Sometimes they are very close to each other. Thus causing the Callouts to over lap. I was thinking if i places a vertical and hidden sinewave geometry. or series of ellipses next to my column I could reach out to the intersection of that path for a placement of my callouts. This would reduce collisions. So Question  1) if I don't display this hidden or same color as background geometry can i perform an intersection calculation? 2) How to perform an intersection calculation in WPF? Would I need to add a horizontal line geometry for each depth item?  Does this make sense.  Oh I tried sending callouts and then moving each rect that was collided. That was a disaster :( Very inneficient. Thanks for any expertise you can guide me with

Comment: can u explain more specific ?? and what you have tried so far ??

Comment: What the code you have wrote? Can you post your XAML/C# code you done so far?